# Cannot program application.onkey for alt+0 in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

In Excel 2016 it seems I cannot program alt + 0 anymore to run a VBA subroutine of mine, in other words 
`application.onkey "%0", "mysub"`
. The default behaviour (to temporary show the ribbon, if hidden) cannot be changed, it seems. But now I also lose alt + shift + 0, in other words the following also does not work:
`application.onkey "%+0", "mysub"`.
Is there any way to have application.onkey override the default action? Thanks

Comment: alt+shift 0 works for me (Excel 2016). WHere is your onkey line of code located precisely? What exactly happens when you run it?

Comment: Thanks I found the problem now .... see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I found the problem now: I had done the ctrl + shift + f1 toggle beforehand. This makes Excel fullscreen and totally hides the ribbon. While hidden, alt + 0 becomes the shortcut to temporarily show the ribbon, and `application.onkey "%0", "mysub"` won't work.

Apologies, it was not my intention to answer my own question from the start... But @jkpieterse motivated to me try harder.

Comment: Great you were able to solve the problem. Although it does surprise me because normally OnKey supersedes whatever the built-in function is a short-cut key triggers.